# Error while updating schwag address in Trailhead account

Tags: salesforce

I'm currently doing Your Journey2Salesforce Learning Path program and in that when I click on collect your salesforce developer schwag I'm getting following error:

We are unable to find your record in our system. If you recently registered to the #Journey2Salesforce program, please wait for 24-48 hours and try again. If you have not registered, please register at sforce.co/j2s

It's been more than a week since I created this account and I still couldn't understand why I'm getting this error message. I rechecked everything twice and my email and username are correct.